# Как обработать не стандартное исключение?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно обработать не стандартное исключение через конструкцию `try - except`?
Возможно я непонятно или неправильно выразился, для примера приведу код ниже:

```
# Это обработка стандартного исключения
>>> f = open('1.txt')
>>> ints = []
>>> try:
...     for line in f:
...         ints.append(int(line))
... except ValueError:
...     print('Это не число. Выходим.')
```

А как правильно указать, к примеру, такое исключение - `selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.164)` через конструкцию `try - except`

На всякий случай, вот как это в териминале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

...
except StaleElementReferenceException
```

Или так

```
from selenium.common import exceptions

...
except exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException
```

и т.д.

А если необязательно выделять именно это исключение, то можно даже просто

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```